# Powershell script install Windows updates associated with a list of IDs

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I have a number of client computers which need many Windows updates installed, but I have limited access to the computers. The Windows Update interface often says there are no updates available, then I manually check for them, and 1 or 2 hours later it has finally collected all 150 important updates that are missing (for instance). But I have difficulty getting access to these machines while people are working on them.

I already have a list of required updates for each of these computers. I'd like to write a script that could turn a list of update IDs into an UpdateCollection which could be downloaded and installed with an UpdateSession. Can this be done?

Edit: I did some more research. Really what I need to be able to do is create an IUpdateCollection object that contains IUpdate objects that are associated with the update IDs I have. If I can get that, I can download and install the updates easily.

Comment: What exactly is the question you want to ask?

Comment: Can I write a Powershell script that can download and install a list of updates (derived from a list of update IDs) without making the Windows Update Agent search for them. I want to skip the search step and get straight to download and install, because we already have the list of updates and Windows Update takes hours to get that list on its own.

Answer (score 0):

This script will force install all updates instead of a list, if you want to install specific updates then the only way to get around this is use something like SCCM to push updates and such, but heres the link.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Force-Install-Updates-on-ef821f9a